# Angular2 routing without leading slash

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

i would glad to get some help with angular 2 routing without a leading slash.

On button click i want to change the current route with the same url but with params.

my current code (**working with a leading slash** ):

```
export const routes: Routes = [
{
    path: 'index.php?option=regular&view=search&Itemid=100/:query',
    component: MainComponent,
},
{
    path: 'index.php',
    component: MainComponent,
}
];
```

On button click:

```
 this.router.navigate([this.router.url, this.searchPramas]);
```

My goal is to replace the slash:

/:query

to

&:query

I saw that thing is maybe possible : [add support for route links with no leading slash](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/07cdc2ff442eb79b0aa1c0c42bfc4f40aa781e97)

Comment: I am thinking you want to pass data to routes , why cant you send data via routes by using data into routes like {path: 'user/:id', component: UserDetailComponent , data: [{userName: 'testname'}]}

Comment: you are using slash in your path, as i wrote, i dont want to use it.

Comment: Can i know why as you are stressing that your url will be same but params will change if that you need not use the  slash al together pass it like a data to the route?

Comment: my mistake,  i am not stressing ,can you please help me config the route file ? this is not working :  {
        path: 'index.php:query',
        component: MainComponent,
    },

Comment: i can give it a try hope it works out what is the ultimate requirement what is it that you want to pass when the user hits thats url